# Disable strict standards in PHP 5.3.8

Tags: php, error-reporting

I am using strict standards option in PHP but I want to disable it because Joomla doesn't like it and I have to use Joomla on my localhost.

In response to another question on this site, this solution was given: `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` but this didn't work for me. I think it only works for PHP 5.4 while I am using 5.3.8.

Can anyone tell me what I should use? I am currently using `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)`. Also I am using `ini_set('display_errors')` but there are still errors shown that are related to strict standards.

So how can I disable strict standard errors?

Comment: `E_STRICT` is not part of `E_ALL` in PHP 5.3, so you might be referring to something different. What does "related to strict standards" mean precisely?

Comment: it worked for me using: ini_set('display_errors',0);
`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);`

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem. This is how I fix it in joomla.

Set error_reporting in configuration.php of joomla to "30711" (equal to E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT)

Comment: OK I think this answers my question. My service provider can turn error reporting off and this will sort the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this little number, gets the entire Joomla website back! Good karma to you...

Answer (score 5):

just messed around with this and would like to share my own results. I did not do it runtime using php, I did it in the php.ini file.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
```

Remeber to restart the server afterwards ....

Answer (score 0):

I tried thanhtd's solution, but it didn't not work for me. However, I changed the error_reporting value to '1' instead of the default '0' in my configuration.php file for Joomla (2) and that worked. So thanks to thanhtd for getting me on the right path.

Answer (score -1):

to suppress all errors use `E_NONE`

you might also want to use `display_errors(0)`

Comment: it worked for me using `ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);`

Comment: @GabrielSantos yes I just wanted to suppress E_STRICT errors and notices e.t.c not all